# Graph on Crystal Reports detail section

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2017

I need to create two simple bars/charts for two values in a row in my database. The connection to the database and the creation of reports are working well..

In the image below is represented with a red circle the type of bar/graph that I need, in MS Access, and that works well.
The problem is that in Visual Studio when creating a Crystal Report, I can not add any type of graphics in the detail section of Crystal Report.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFeek.png)

Does Crystal Reports not allow you to create charts in the details section? Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Charts should be inserted into the Footer sections and can't be used in Header or Detail sections.

To get around this limitation you can group by the primary key of your data rows, move the fields in the Details Section to the Header or Footer for this group, and then insert the chart into the Footer for this group.  Then suppress the Details section.

If this is a large report, this could impact performance quite a bit though.  Rendering lots of charts takes a good amount of resources.